# How can I get data on the next row from another worksheet when I click the button?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can I copy data from a worksheet ("Actual Request") like this:

```
Treaty:                          Property per risk  
Treaty currency:                 EUR    
Line of business of the risk:    Property   
New / Renewal:                   New    
Insured Company /Name of risk:   MNM Company    
Occupancy / risk details:    The risk is ...
```

to another worksheet ("Historical Requests") which looks like:

```
Treaty  Treaty  Currency    Line of business    New / Renewal   Insured Company
```

I have to transfer the data on "Historical Requests" by clicking a button. Also, when I pun other information on the "Actual Request" worksheet I would like to put this new information on the next row (keeping the existing information on the "Historical Requests").
I found the code below but it has a problem because it overwrite the existing information from the "Historical Requests"

Hope I was clear.
Looking forward to your response.
Thanks.

```
Sub TransferToHistory()
'
' TransferToHistory Macro
'

'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 3).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 4).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 5).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 6).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 7).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 8).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 9).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 10).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("C13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 11).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 12).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B17").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 13).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 14).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 15).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("B20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Select
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 16).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("Actual Request").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, to avoid overwriting "historical requests" you can check last dirty row , using something like: `activesheet.range("d1").end(xldown).select `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the data and transpose the data while pasting. Below is the code to do that.

```
Sub Macro4()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Actual Request").Range("B24", Range("B24").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Historical Requests").Range("A1").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Note**: I'm not yet entirely sure how your data is in "**Actual Request**" sheet. So this may not give you the expected result.